# Display a modal window when ModelState is valid ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app in Visual Studio 2022, using database-first approach in Entity Framework.

I have a user model called `Usuario`; a controller `UsuarioController` and a view model for this login form called `LoginViewModel`:

`LoginViewModel`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace KadabraMVC.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo es requerido.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",
            ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una Dirección de Correo electrónico válida..")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Longitud máxima 100")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress,
            ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una Dirección de Correo electrónico válida.")]
        public string Mail { get; set; } = null!;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo es requerido.")]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Longitud entre 4 y 15 caracteres.",
                      MinimumLength = 4)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Contraseña { get; set; } = null!;

        [Display(Name = "Recordarme")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the login view, there is a simple form with 2 text inputs for email and password, then a submit button.

`Login` view:

```
@using KadabraMVC.ViewModels
@model LoginViewModel;

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="ConsultarCredenciales">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Mail" class="control-label"></label> 
                <input asp-for="Mail" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Mail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contraseña" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contraseña" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contraseña" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

I want to add this code for a modal view to pop up when the user credentials are valid (I know I have to add `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"` to the button to call the modal)

```
<div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">
        <div id="exampleModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog alert-success" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content ">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title ">¡Registro Exitoso!</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            @*este es la cruz de arriba a la derecha*@
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            <div class="accept-policy">Te has registrado correctamente.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I press the submit button in the form, it calls the `ConsultarCredenciales()` method in the `UsuarioController`, which checks if it is any user in the database with those credentials.

`ConsultarCredenciales()`:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ConsultarCredenciales(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var UsuarioLogin = new Usuario()
                {
                    Mail = model.Mail,
                    Contraseña = model.Contraseña,
                };

        var UsuariosQueCoinciden = from q in _context.Usuarios
                                   where q.Mail == UsuarioLogin.Mail && q.Contraseña == UsuarioLogin.Contraseña
                                   select q;

        if (UsuariosQueCoinciden.Any()) //If any user matches, i define that user (from db) as mi actual user.
        {
            UsuarioLogin = UsuariosQueCoinciden.First();
            ViewBag.UsuarioActual = UsuarioLogin; // I think here is where I have to load the "Succesful" modal

            return Redirect(nameof(InicioUsuario)); //returns to 
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.UsuarioActual = 0; //no esta terminado esto
        }
    }

    return Redirect(nameof(Index));
}
```

What I want to do is that when the user clicks the button:

1. Normal `ConsultarCredenciales()` behavior, checking if the user exists
2. When the user **exists**, the modal view appears in front, only saying "successful login"
3. Then, return the profile view for this user.

I was looking for similar problems but my Javascript and jQuery knowledge is basic.

Also tried to load or "make appear" the modal when I click the button from the View and from the controller.

Disclaimer: this is my first post, if I have to modify anything let me know

My project structure:

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5NJW.png)

Comment: I think this might be solved using a Partial View, but still, I don't know how to implement it **when the ModelState is Valid**.

Comment: 1) never store passwords as clear text. 2) You will need to give the browser a cookie (or something) to identify the user when they make further requests. You might as well solve both these problems, and many others, by using the MS Identity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try below method:

After the Form is submitted, the  Model object returned from the Controller is checked for NULL and if it is not NULL then  "successful login" is displayed using JavaScript Alert MessageBox.

1. Return the model to the view

   ```
    if (UsuariosQueCoinciden.Any()) //If any user matches, i define that user (from db) as mi actual user.
        {
           return View(model);  

        }
   ```

2.In the view add

```
@if (Model != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                alert("successful login " );
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @ch0c, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.